# Fish Shell returning status code from within command substitution

Tags: pipe, status, fish

I have a little helper function that works like this:

```
function select_item
  set -e selected_item
  set -g selected_item (for i in $argv; echo $i; end | fzf)
end
```

This function is then used elsewhere to fire up editors or whatever.

What I'd like to be able to do, is abort everything, if I hit escape in `fzf`, and pass the error status code (from `fzf`) on to the calling client functions, so they can also abort.  But, I think that the status code returned from function `select_item` is from the success or failure of the final `set` command rather than the last operation feeding into it from `fzf`.

Is there a clean way to get at the status code of `fzf` while retaining this nice pipe based code structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$status will contain the status of fzf not set:

```sh
$ set output (date; false)
$ printf "%s\n" $status $output
1
Tue Aug  4 18:43:22 EDT 2020
```

You can use printf in place of that for loop to add the newlines:

```
function select_item
  set -e selected_item
  set -g selected_item (printf "%s\n" $argv | fzf)
  return $status
end
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn.  Will give it a try today.